# Edit "topbar" in dynamics crm hubs

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365

I can not find a way to edit the "topbar" that is used in Dynamics CRM hubs. I am able to edit certain elements with the sitemap, but not the topbar in the hubs.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ormZB.png)

Any advise would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit it not using SiteMap but using Ribbon Workbench. Following post describes what to do - http://develop1.net/public/post/2018/03/07/Adding-Global-Command-Buttons-to-the-Unified-Interface-

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I was able to add custom buttons as well as hide a few unwanted ones. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!!